# Custom tag with more than one attribute and function?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

which is proper way to write more than one attribute and more than one function in single tld file i.e. in custom tag.

here is tags in code:

```
     <tag>
        <name>cardwidgettags</name>
        <tag-class>com.sciformix.sciportal.apps.dap.CardWidget</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>

        <attribute>
            <name>title</name>
            <required>true</required>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>link</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>icon</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>




    </tag> 
    <function>
            <name>addLineItem</name>
            <function-class>.dap.CardWidget</function-class>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
            <function-signature>void addLineItem(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

how to call this in one time from jsp page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Into your tld file you can do something like this:

**functions.tld**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <taglib version="2.1"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">

        <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
        <short-name>functions</short-name>
        <uri>http://anyurl.com/myfunctions</uri>  <!-- define url to access functions from jsp file -->

        <function>
            <name>functionOne</name> <!-- function name -->
            <function-class>com.mypackage.MyUtilClass</function-class> <!-- full path to your class where define function -->
            <function-signature>void functionOne(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)</function-signature>
        </function>

        <function>
            <name>functionTwo</name> <!-- function name -->
            <function-class>com.mypackage.MyUtilClass</function-class> <!-- full path to your class where define function -->
         <function-signature>void functionTwo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
        </function>

  </taglib>
```

**myjsp.jsp**

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="myfnc" uri="http://anyurl.com/myfunctions" %> <!-- url is defined above -->
...
${myfnc:functionTwo("str1","str2", "str3")}
${myfnc:functionOnw(1, 2, 3)}
```